# Changing Apache2.2.11 httpd.conf has no effect

Tags: apache, timeout, httpd.conf

Hopefully someone can help here.
I recently installed wampserver ver 2.0 with Apache ver 2.2.11.
My issue is, I have some large php scripts which timeout at the default 5 min (300 sec) browser limit (I'm using ie8). It is critcal I get this limit extended.
I have tried changing the httpd.conf file to include the following:
TimeOut 1200
My objective was to set the timeout at 1200 seconds, or 20 min.
I had just chosen a random location to place this directive within the httpd.conf file as I cannot locate any documentation to suggest it belongs in a specific place within the file. Regardless, the changes I make appear in the httpd.conf file that can be found in the system tray for wampserver, however they have no effect - the browser still times out after 5 minutes.
I thought perhaps I had the capitals incorrect, so I changed to:
Timeout 1200
This change had no effect either.
Can someone please help, this is very frustrating. Maybe the command can only be used within a specific module? If so, I have no idea which one, nor do I know the syntax to specify this.
Regards
Adrian.

Comment: And you reloaded the server after the change?

Comment: Mmmhh, what are you doing that keeps > 5 minutes to process?

Maybe you should start your processing task and use push or pull technique via ajax to check if your process is finished?

Comment: not a code issue. belongs on serverfault

Comment: also I'm considering downmodding 'solid block of text' more use of whitespace please.

Answer (score 1):

You say that the 5 minutes is a browser limit, yet you expect this to change when you amend your webserver config.

Check your settings for:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER--Software--Microsoft--Windows--CurrentVersion--InternetSettings--ReceiveTimeout

(DWORD valie in milliseconds)

However that's not really how to fix the problem: HTTP is all about stateless, fast response. Start bending the rules and you're going to get into trouble. The right way to fix the problem is to dissociate the long running process from the webserver and poll back its status.

C.

Comment: Hi C,

I actually tried the regedit solution - no success there either.

This process is not for an online website. It simply processes a large amount of data from my database for me, so I am the only person that ever has to wait.

Once the process is complete, it is not a worry. But because the browser keeps timing out, it never completes!

I had no problems with previous versions of wampserver, but my previous installation was with XP, I've now just set it up on Win 7, and I have these problems.

Adrian